# Вывод картинок циклом в Parcel JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Использую Parcel.js, начал писать код вывода картинок циклом и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В [документации](https://parceljs.org/recipes/image/#javascript) сказано, что картинки выводятся через конструктор `new URL()`.
Пример:

```js
img.src = new URL('hero.jpg', import.meta.url);
```

Я пытался вывести картинки посредством цикла, написав примерно следующий код:

```js
arrayImg.forEach(img => {
    let img = new URL(img, import.meta.url);
    ...
});
```

Но оказалось, что конструктор `new URL()` принимает только `string literal` — строку, окруженную двойными или одинарными кавычками.

> The first argument must be a string literal to be recognized (not a variable or expression).

Проще говоря, вставлять в конструктор нужно путь к файлу вида `'/src/img/image.png'`, но такой вариант для массовой выгрузки картинок не годится, не будешь же каждую картинку вручную прописывать в конструкторе

```js
let img1 = new URL('/src/img/image1.png', import.meta.url);
let img2 = new URL('/src/img/image2.png', import.meta.url);
let img3 = new URL('/src/img/image3.png', import.meta.url);
let img4 = new URL('/src/img/image4.png', import.meta.url);
...
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, как же мне вывести картинки циклом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, массово картинки в Parcel достаются с помощью Glob.
https://parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#glob-specifiers

В вашем коде нужно будет прописать импорт картинок из нужной папки так

```js
import img from '/img/*.jpg';
```

`img` будет содержать объекты ваших картинок вида

```js
{
  'имя картинки': 'урл до нее'
}
```

После чего, сможете доставать эти картинки у себя в цикле используя `img[imgName]`

Comment: Спасибо) Но что делать, если нужно достать из папки не все картинки, или они разного расширения?

Comment: @anket Можете сделать отдельную папку только под нужные картинки и доставать оттуда. ЧТо касается разных расширений, можно например, прописать вторую строку `import imgPng from '/img/*.png';`, а потом объединить объекты `img` и `imgPng`